# Under what conditions is a POVM a von Neumann measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

I want to know a definition of a von Neumann measurement. Because I can't find this concept referenced correctly in internet, and what differentiates it from a POVM, that by definition is the measurement with operators $\{E_i\}$ that

- Are positive definite
- $\sum_i E_i = \mathbb{I}$
- Probability preserving.

But what condition do we have to add to this POVM measurement to have a von Neumann measurement?

Comment: Just looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#History_of_the_measurement_concept) I gather that the operators $E_i$ in the POVM have to be self-adjoint (Hermitian). Von Neumann requires only a single operator that is self-adjoint and does not have to be positive definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You only need the first two requirements for a [POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM). You need Hermitian operators $\{E_i\}$ such that $E_i\ge0$ and $\sum_i E_i=I$. I'm not sure what you mean with them being "probability preserving".
2. Presumably, by a "von Neumann measurement" you mean a *projective-valued measurement*, in this context often abbreviated with PVM. These are POVMs whose elements are projections. In other words, collections $\{E_i\}$ such that $E_i\ge0$, $\sum_i E_i=I$, *and* $E_i^2=E_i$.

Comment: "Probability preserving" = "sum of outcome probabilities = 1".

Comment: A key property which is worth pointing out separately is that the $E_i$ must project onto orthogonal subspaces. While these follows from the conditions you list, it is quite fine-tuned, as all three of those are required. E.g., a SIC-POVM has $E_i$ which are only *proportional* to projectors, which alllows them to no longer be orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

A von Neumann measurement is defined by an observable (Hermitian operator), the spectral decomposition of which gives a set of mutually orthogonal projectors (Nielsen Sec. 2.2.5) .

So the additional condition is that the POVM effects are orthogonal projectors, i.e. $E_i E_j = \delta_{ij} E_i$.

Update thanks to the comment: The condition that $E_i E_i = E_i$ is equivalent with $E_i E_j = \delta_{ij} E_i$, which is explained also in [projectors sum to identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542878/projection-matrix-that-sum-to-identity-are-orthogonal).

Comment: Since the $E_i$ are hermitian and sum to the identity, the condition $E_i^2=E_i$ indeed implies orthogonality. (Otherwise, their sum would have an eigenvalue >1.) -- P.S.: If you have a mistake in an answer, generally edit it rather than deleting and re-posting it.